# Implementing abstract class members in a parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

**Is it possible to implement an abstract base class with members inherited from another parent class in C++?**

It works in C#, so I tried doing it in C++:

```
// Virtual destructors omitted for brevity

class ITalk
{
public:
    virtual void SayHi() = 0;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    void SayHi();
};

class Child : public Parent, public ITalk
{
};

void Parent::SayHi()
{
    std::printf("Hi\n");
}
```

My compiler didn't really like it though:

```
ITalk* lChild = new Child(); // You idiot, Child is an abstract class!
lChild->SayHi();
```

I can't *add* `public ITalk` to the `Parent` class because "base-class 'ITalk' is already a base-class of 'Parent'." I could *move* `public ITalk` up to the `Parent` class, but in my particular scenario that complicates a lot of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because what you really have is two base classes without any knowledge of each other.

```
Italk    Parent
 / \       / \
  |         |
  +---------+
       |
     Child
```

If Parent and Italk had two variables named i, there'd be two instances of "i", ITalk::i and Parent::i. To access them you'd have to fully qualify which one you wanted.

The same is true of methods, lChild has two methods called SayHi and you need to clarify which one you mean when calling SayHi because the multiple inheritance has made it ambiguous.

You have Parent's SayHi

```
lChild->Parent::SayHi();
```

and Italk's SayHi:

```
lChild->ITalk::SayHi();
```

The latter is pure virtual and because its abstract needs to be overridden locally in Child. To satisfy this you'll need to define

```
Child::SayHi();
```

Which would now hide Parent::SayHi() when invoking SayHi without scoping it to the class:

```
lChild->SayHi() //parent's now hidden, invoke child's
```

Of course Child::SayHi() could call Parent::SayHi():

```
void Child::SayHi()
{
     Parent::SayHi();
}
```

which would solve your problem.

Comment: This makes it clearer how the compiler sees the functions. Would it be correct to say that the compiler only looks at the local class, and will not search the inheritance tree, when looking for the overriding implementation of `ITalk::SayHi()`?

Comment: Yes that is true. When instantiating an object, the compiler looks UP from what you're instantiating and makes sure that anything still pure virtual directly above it has been instantiated **locally**.

Answer (score 1):

`ITalk` contains the pure virtual function `SayHi()`, so if you want to be able to instantiate a class that derives from `ITalk` that class must implement `SayHi()`.

```
class Child : public Parent, public ITalk
{
public:
  void SayHi() { std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl; }
};
```

Alternatively, `Parent` can inherit from `ITalk` (but not `Child`) and the code you've posted will work.

Also, when implementing a base class with virtual functions you *must* define virtual destructors for those base classes. So ITalk should be:

```
class ITalk
{
public:
    virtual void SayHi() = 0;
    virtual ~ITalk() {}
};
```

If you don't do that the following produces undefined behavior

```
ITalk* lChild = new Child();
lChild->SayHi();
delete lChild;
```

Comment: So... no? The `Child` class cannot inherit the members that it wants to use to implement `ITalk`?

Comment: @emddudley Yep, can't do it. Doug T.'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167558/implementing-abstract-class-members-in-a-parent-class/7167649#7167649) explains why

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to be done as you wrote it. The reason behind it is, that every non-static method needs object (`this`) to operate on (here you don't use any of the object's fields or methods, but that doesn't matter), and this object must be of apropriate type. `Parent::sayHi` expects `this` to be of the type `Parent`, and since `ITalk` is not related to `Parent` at all, `Parent::sayHi` and `ITalk::sayHi` methods are fundamentaly incompatible.

C++ is having static type system, so the type must be known at compile time. Languages that use dynamic typing are usually less strict about such constructions, as they can test if object is of apropriate class at function call.

In C++ the easiest way to implement such behavior would be to simply make `Child::sayHi` to call `Parent::sayHi`, as Child is the only class that "knows" where are `Parent` and `ITalk` and how should they be related.

```
class Child : public Parent, public ITalk
{
    virtual void sayHi(){ Parent::sayHi(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use virtual inheritance

```
class ITalk
{
public:
  virtual void SayHi() = 0;
};

class Parent: virtual ITalk
{
public:
   void SayHi();
};

class Child : public Parent, public virtual ITalk
{
};

void Parent::SayHi()
{
    std::printf("Hi\n");
}
```