# Why using cannot be used to define a virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding, using-declaration

I've recently discovered the use of `using` to import a base class function into the namespace of a derived class (when it is being hidden). I was trying to use it to import a function from a base class as an implementation of the function in a derived class:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
  void foo() {
  }  
};

class C : public A, public B {
public:
  using B::foo;
};


int main()
{
  C c;
}
```

This won't compile as `A::foo()` is a pure virtual function in `C`. I was hoping that `using B::foo;` would make an implementation of `foo()`. Why isn't it so ?

Comment: `using` has nothing to do with overriding. It only affects *name lookup*.

Comment: @VincentFourmond: The `using` declaration here is redundant since even without it `C` will be inheriting `B::foo`, it's not _hidden_ yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use inheritance to implement an interface in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533772/why-cant-i-use-inheritance-to-implement-an-interface-in-c)

Comment: @KerrekSB Post as an _answer_!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing abstract class members in a parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167558/implementing-abstract-class-members-in-a-parent-class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C++ not let baseclasses implement a derived class' inherited interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464308/why-does-c-not-let-baseclasses-implement-a-derived-class-inherited-interface)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, close it since we've multiple dupes :)

Comment: @legends2k: True true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two *different* functions: `A::foo()` and `B::foo()`. Although they have the same unqualified name, they are *not* related. `B::foo()` does not and cannot override `A::foo()` because `B` is not a subclass of `A`.

`C` inherits both functions from `A` and `B`. You use public inheritance for both base classes, so `A::foo()` and `B::foo()` are *already visible* in `C` (note that you need qualified name to invoke the functions to avoid ambiguity). 
So your using declaration has actually no effect.

---

A using declaration, when used inside a class, has to do with *[overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)*, but it has nothing to do with *[overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)*. These are *very different concepts*.

*Overloading* is about having different functions with the same name but different argument sets.

*Overriding* is about polymorphism, i.e. having varying implementations of a base-class method in derived classes.

---

A using declaration introduces a function name from a base class into a derived class, where that name would be hidden by another function with the same name *but different arguments*. For example:

```
class X
{  
 public:
  void func() {}
};

class Y : public X 
{  
 public:
  void func(int arg) {}
};
```

`Y::func` *does not override* `X::func`, since its arguments are different. Moreover, it also *hides* the name `func` from the base class, so it can be called only via qualified name, e.g.:

```
X x; 
x.func(); // ok

Y y; 
y.func(1); // ok, Y::func called 
y.func(); // error, base-class name func is hidden by local name 
y.X::func(); // ok, qualified name, X::func called
```

In this case, a using declaration would introduce the name from the base class into the derived class, making `func` callable without name-qualifying:

```
class Y : public X 
{  
 public:
  using X::func; 
  void func(int arg) {}
};

// ...

Y y; 
y.func(); // ok, X::func called
```

Answer (score 0):

`using` in C++ has  a different meaning and designates that you would like to be able to access a function/object in another **namespace** without typing the namespace name explicitly. It has nothing to do with overriding.

Comment: Nothing to do with classes? That's not quite true; [you can bring members from a base class into scope](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/overcoming-name-shadowing-in-c/).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: +1 Yeah, it's the remedy when _Derived::f(char)_ **hides** _Base::f(double)_.